# Using Java lambdas or streams to convert list of POJOs into a list of their IDs

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to broaden my Java horizons and start actually writing Java 8+ code. I have a situation where I have a list of POJOs (each POJO instancehas an `id : Long` field) and I need to produce a `List<Long>` representing all of their `ids`. Here's my code that works perfectly fine:

```
List<Fizzbuzz> fizzbuzzes = getFizzbuzzes();
List<Long> fbIds = new ArrayList<>();
for(Fizzbuzz fb : fizzbuzzes) {
    fbIds.add(fb.getId());
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a more "modern" Java 8+ way (lambdas or collections tricks, streaming, etc.) to write this code. Any ideas or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: `fizzbuzzes.stream().map(Fizzbuzz::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- *Stream* the list of `Fizzbuzz`
- *map* this stream to a `Stream<Long>`
- and finally *collect* it into a `List<Long>`.

It would give :

```
List<Long> fbIds = getFizzbuzzes().stream()
                                  .map(Fizzbuzz::getId)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 fizzbuzzes.stream()
           .map(Fizzbuzz::getId)
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 4):

sure you can:

```
fizzbuzzes.stream() 
          .map(e -> e.getId()) 
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

That way would be better, using Java 8 streams and method reference:

```
List<Long> fbIds = fizzbuzzes.stream().map(Fizzbuzz::getid).collect(Collectors.toList());
```